# Maven not updating EAR with latest code in workspace after maven-install

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-2

I have a multi-module maven spring project with a main parent module(parent pom):

1. project
2. project-client
3. project-ear
4. project-filenet
5. project-jaxws
6. project-webservice
7. project-service-util
8. project-properties

When a maven clean install is performed the resulting EAR file does not have the updated version of project-jaxws, project-service-util and project-filenet module.

I have repeatedly tried recleaning it and installing it, restarting STS, restarting the machine but to no avail. Please explain why maven behaves this way and what to do to make maven build the EAR properly.

Parent pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.abc.technology.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>global-parent</artifactId>
        <version>24</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.abc.technology</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0.1-RC10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>abc project Application</name>    
    <description>abc project web service and application</description>

    <properties>
        <!-- You will need to modify this property. It must point to the root of
        your projects trunk/tags/branches structure. It is used by the Jenkins
        Branch, Snapshot and Formal release builds to determine the correct locations
        for publishing of tags and branches. It is also used in the Maven SCM section
        below until the first Snapshot release at which point it will be token replaced
        with the full value  -->
        <svn.root>${svn.base.url}/Technology/project</svn.root>

        <!-- No requirement to statically analyse generated code -->
        <sonar.skippedModules>project-ear</sonar.skippedModules>
        <sonar.exclusions>com/ibm/**/*.java,org/**/*.java,**/EJS*.java,**com/abc/services/exceptions/*.java,**com/abc/services/common/commondatatypes/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/framework/abcheader/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/technology/documentdsm/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/technology/enterprisedocumentservicecomponents/v1/*java,**com/abc/technology/project/contract/v1/*.java,**com/abc/technology/project/service/v1/*.java,**com/abc/technology/project/constants/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
        <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:${svn.root}/branches/project-2.0.0</connection>

<developerConnection>scm:svn:${svn.root}/branches/project-2.0.0</developerConnection>

<url>http://kau1p464.abc.com/svn/Technology/project/branches/project-2.0.0</url>
    </scm>

    <!-- Dependencies which are global to all modules -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Test dependencies, not present in application assembly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Only required to support STS / Eclipse compilation
        Has "provided" scope in global-parent pom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>

        <module>project-filenet</module>
        <module>project-service-util</module>
        <module>project-webservice</module>
        <module>project-jaxws</module>
        <module>project-client</module>
        <module>project-ear</module>
    <module>project-properties</module>
  </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.tech.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>service-invocation</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.technology.services</groupId>
                <artifactId>manageform-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.tech.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>service-invocation-cxf</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.technology.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>webservicerouting</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.4</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

project-jaxws pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.abc.technology</groupId>
        <version>2.0.0.1-RC10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project-jaxws</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>abc project JAXWS Jar</name>
    <description>Implements the technology layer for exposing the abc project service via JAXWS</description>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- business contract definition (Service interface and domain objects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-filenet</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- abc service invocation framework support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.tech.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-invocation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.tech.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-invocation-cxf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- This dependency is provided at Runtime by a concrete implementation, 
        it is required to be referenced here to support compile time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 181 support
            Only required to support STS / Eclipse compilation. Has "provided" scope 
            in global-parent pom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 250 support
            Only required to support STS / Eclipse compilation. Has "provided" scope 
            in global-parent pom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Support for AOP application of abc standard logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.tech.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspect-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.filenet.p8</groupId>
            <artifactId>jace</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-service-util</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.technology.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservicerouting</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.technology.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>manageform-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.abc.technology.eal</groupId>
  <artifactId>ealframework</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <!-- This profile is active by default and will weave the logging aspects 
        into your byte code. The profile however may be disabled by running your 
        maven command line with the -P !weave-aspects switch, e.g. mvn clean install 
        -P !weave-aspects This is often useful when carrying out remote debugging 
        in the development environment as it removes the noise of the woven aspect 
        when tracing the execution path -->
    <profiles>
        <!-- <profile>
            <id>weave-aspects</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
        </profile> -->

        <profile>
            <id>generate-service-classes</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-sources</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceRoot>
                                    <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                                    <wsdlOptions>
                                        <!-- <wsdlOption>
                                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ManageDocument/Technology-ManageDocument.wsdl</wsdl>
                                            <bindingFiles>
                                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws/jaxws-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                            </bindingFiles>
                                            <extraargs>
                                                Argument generates the JAX-WS service endpoint implementation class
                                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg />
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/ManageDocument/service/v1=com.abc.technology.managedocument.service.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/ManageDocument/contract/v1=com.abc.technology.managedocument.contract.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/framework/abcHeader/v2</extraarg>
                                            </extraargs>
                                        </wsdlOption> -->
                                        <!-- <wsdlOption>
                                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/RetrieveDocument/Technology-RetrieveDocument.wsdl</wsdl>
                                            <bindingFiles>
                                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws/jaxws-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                            </bindingFiles>
                                            <extraargs>
                                                Argument generates the JAX-WS service endpoint implementation class
                                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg />
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/RetrieveDocument/service/v1=com.abc.technology.retrievedocument.service.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/RetrieveDocument/contract/v1=com.abc.technology.retrievedocument.contract.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/framework/abcHeader/v2</extraarg>
                                            </extraargs>
                                        </wsdlOption> -->
                                        <wsdlOption>
                                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/RetrieveDocumentMetadata/Technology-RetrieveDocumentMetadata.wsdl</wsdl>
                                            <bindingFiles>
                                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws/jaxws-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                            </bindingFiles>
                                            <extraargs>
                                                <!-- Argument generates the JAX-WS service endpoint implementation class -->
                                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg />
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/RetrieveDocumentMetadata/service/v1=com.abc.technology.retrievedocumentmetadata.service.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/RetrieveDocumentMetadata/contract/v1=com.abc.technology.retrievedocumentmetadata.contract.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/framework/abcHeader/v2</extraarg>
                                            </extraargs>
                                        </wsdlOption>
                                        <!-- <wsdlOption>
                                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/SearchDocument/Technology-SearchDocument.wsdl</wsdl>
                                            <bindingFiles>
                                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws/jaxws-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                            </bindingFiles>
                                            <extraargs>
                                                Argument generates the JAX-WS service endpoint implementation class
                                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg />
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/service/v1=com.abc.technology.searchdocument.service.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/contract/v1=com.abc.technology.searchdocument.contract.v1</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>http://services.abc.com/framework/abcHeader/v2</extraarg>
                                            </extraargs>
                                        </wsdlOption> -->
                                    </wsdlOptions>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <sonar.exclusions>com/ibm/**/*.java,org/**/*.java,**/EJS*.java,**com/abc/services/exceptions/*.java,**com/abc/services/common/commondatatypes/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/framework/abcheader/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/technology/documentdsm/v1/*.java,**com/abc/services/technology/enterprisedocumentservicecomponents/v1/*java,**com/abc/technology/project/contract/v1/*.java,**com/abc/technology/project/service/v1/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post EAR POM.

Comment: where is ear pom/maven-ear-plugin definition?